# UTF8 characters with Wireshark

Tags: utf-8, wireshark

I have a Wireshark capture file that contains some XML encoded in UTF8. Unfortunately Wireshark doesn't play well with UTF8 so I have strings like `×©×\231×\227×\225×ª` in my file. How can I decode these or, even better, let Wireshark decode these on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something gets mangled when Wireshark saves the file as text. I ended up saving the bytes to file and writing a ruby script to interpret them as UTF8. I'm sure there's a better solution but I don't know what it is.